# SQL Max and Double Join

Tags: sql

I have the following three tables:

```
student
-------
stnumb
stname
gender
grade
born

subject
-------
subjnumb
subjname
tname

results
-------
stnumb
subjnumb
percent
```

I need to return the `highest result and its subject for each student`

*Example*: **Bob Smith, IPT, 92**

Two closest results I've had are:

```
SELECT  stname
    ,   subjname
    ,   highestmark
FROM    (
            SELECT      MAX(results.percent) as "highestmark"
                    ,   student.stname
                    ,   subject.subjname
            FROM        student
                    ,   subject
                    ,   results
            WHERE       results.stnumb      = student.stnumb
            AND         results.subjnumb    = subject.subjnumb
            GROUP BY    stname
        ) maxresult
```

...and...

```
SELECT      student.stname as Student
        ,   subject.subjname as Subject
        ,   results.percent as Mark
FROM        results 
JOIN        student
ON          results.stnumb = student.stnumb
JOIN        subject
ON          results.subjnumb = subject.subjnumb
ORDER BY    stname
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I've been working on it for days and aren't making any ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by missing **subjname** in GROUP BY, this is MySql. MySql does not have analytical functions, so you need to summon older forms of top 1. There is a version with derived table holding maximums. This table is used to filter original tables:

```
SELECT      student.stname as Student
        ,   subject.subjname as Subject
        ,   results.percent as Mark
FROM        results 
JOIN        student
ON          results.stnumb = student.stnumb
JOIN        subject
ON          results.subjnumb = subject.subjnumb
JOIN
(
   SELECT stnumb, MAX(percent) percent
     FROM results
    GROUP BY stnumb
) top1GradePerStudent
  ON results.stnumb = top1GradePerStudent.stnumb
 AND results.percent = top1GradePerStudent.percent
ORDER BY    stname
```

There is also `not exists` approach, retrieving only student records that do not have higher percent:

```
SELECT      student.stname as Student
        ,   subject.subjname as Subject
        ,   results.percent as Mark
FROM        results 
JOIN        student
ON          results.stnumb = student.stnumb
JOIN        subject
ON          results.subjnumb = subject.subjnumb
WHERE       NOT EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT null
                  FROM results r2
                 WHERE r2.stnumb = results.stnumb
                   AND r2.percent > results.percent
            )
ORDER BY    stname
```

Both ways will return ties. If you have to have one record per student, enclose `subjname` in MAX or MIN, as all other data in row will be the same so it doesn't really matter which subject you pick.

P.S. I didn't test this queries. There might be a typo, but basic approach is correct.

Comment: Mate, You're LEGEND! Thankyou Very Much!!! The first query works absolutely perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pct, subjname, stname 
FROM
(SELECT r.pct, sub.subjname, std.stname,
RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY sub.subjname ORDER BY r.pct) as rk
FROM student std 
INNER JOIN results r ON r.stnumb = std.stnumb 
INNER JOIN subject sub ON sub.subjnumb = r.subjnumb 
GROUP BY sub.subjname, std.stname, r.pct ) a
WHERE rk = 1
```

Comment: "It didn't work" is very vague, what specifically are you having issues with? I have tested the query in a sqlfiddle and it executes. While I have no knowledge of your data structure beyond what you have provided, I can't make an assumption as to what will 'work'. The approach I suggested with `RANK() OVER (PARTION BY ..ORDER BY..)` is the correct approach to solving the problem you outlined.

Comment: I know, it's vague but I can't give any reason as to why not, all it does when you enter an incorrect query is not return anything, so the issue could be anywhere. If I knew more, I would say so.